# Action on spawned sprites cocos2d-x

Tags: touch, cocos2d-x, action, sprite

in my code I spawn a sprite every 1.5 seconds but when I touch the sprite works only on the last spawned sprite, how can I make it work with all the sprites?

My code: (not all)

```
void HelloWorld::spawnRedThing(float dt) {
//actions for spawning the sprite
}

bool HelloWorld::onTouchBegan(cocos2d::Touch *touch, cocos2d::Event *event)
{
//actions on touching
}

bool HelloWorld::init()
{

//create touch listener
auto listener = EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();
listener->setSwallowTouches(true);
listener->onTouchBegan = CC_CALLBACK_2(HelloWorld::onTouchBegan, this);
_eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(listener, this);

//create timer for spawning sprites 
this->schedule(schedule_selector(HelloWorld::spawnRedThing), 1.5);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes,it works,spriteList is at outSide like this:

```
local spriteList = {}  
local function spawnRedThing(dt)
  local sprite = cc.Sprite:create("land.png")
  table.insert(spriteList,sprite)
end

local function touchBegan(touch,event)
  for index,obj in pairs(spriteList) do
    if cc.rectContainsPoint(obj:getBoundingBox(),touch:getLocation()) then
      --sprite touched
    end
  end
  return true
end
```

Comment: ok i am trying but i don't understand the "for" part, can you explain me in c++? what is "obj in pairs"?

Comment: `Vector<Sprite*>  vec1;
//addSprite
vec1.pushBack(sprite);

//for part
for(auto sp : vec1)
{
    //....
}`

how to use Vector,you can check here:
[link](http://cocos2d-x.org/docs/manual/framework/native/v3/data-structure/vector/en)

Answer (score 0):

in function onTouchBegan()  you need check every sprite that you spawn,so you need to set all sprite into a list ,and check if it's be touched
my code is lua:

```
local spriteList = {}
for index,obj in pairs(spriteList) then
    if cc.rectContainsPoint(obj:getBoundingBox(),touch.getLocation()) then
      --touched
    end
end
```

Comment: But I spawn only a sprite several times, so if I add it in the list is the same thing